# Visual Studio Freezes when I try to Add a file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that I'm working on in Visual Studio 2013 Premium.  I have three projects that are underneath my solution.   If I right-click on any of the folders that are immediately under my solution and choose add, the flyout from the context menu displays fine and Visual Studio continues to function normally.

If I right click on any (I've tried a few but not all) folder underneath one particular project in Visual Studio, it freezes for about fifteen minutes.  The cpu and memory usage when this is going on seem pretty normal.

If I right click on any of the folders underneath the other two projects and choose Add I get the flyout to appear showing the types of things I can add to the folder and everything works just fine.

What I've tried:

- Disabling all Visual Studio Extensions that can be disabled.  This didn't fix it.
- Starting an instance of Visual Studio in Safe mode, this does fix it.

Any idea what I can try next?  I'd hate to have to manually uninstall all of the Visual Studio extensions that can't be disabled, but this seems like the logical next course of action.

As far as Extensions I have:

```
Application Insights Behaviors SDK (XAML) 
Bing Dev. Assistant (Disabled, installed after problem started) 
Find in Solution Explorer (Disabled) 
Company-created Build Tools (Disabled) 
Company-created Core Tools 
Company-created Scaffolding Tools (Disabled) 
Microsoft Advertising pubCenter
Microsoft Advertising SDK for Win 8.1
Microsoft Advertising SDK for WP 8.1 XAML
Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools
Microsoft Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC 5 Scaffolding
Nuget Package Manager
Productivity Power Tools (Disabled)
Release Management for VS 2013
TFS Server Power Tools for VS 2013
TFS Sidekicks (Disabled)
TFS Process Template Editor
TFS Team Collab.
TFS Work Item Type Designer
Unit Test Generator (Disabled)
Visual F#
VS Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript
WP 8.1 SDK Integration
Workflow Manager Activities
```

I don't need the WP 8.1 stuff here at work, but dabble with it at home.  Since I'm logged into my MSDN account in Visual Studio at both places,  would it uninstall it from my home PC if I uninstall it at work?

I'm doing a little further exploration.   On the project that has the problem, when I try to do an add to a folder, I'm seeing Nuget.exe get fired off every six seconds over and over again.  Where would I look to see where this is set up?  I assume in the .csproj file.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect your project/solution is either doing a build or running tests when adding a file. This is probably caused by an extension you have. What extensions are installed?

Comment: Disable all AV components.

Comment: AV components = Anti-Virus?

Comment: @eric: yes. It is notorious for malfunctioning databases, and a lot of other programs.

Answer (score 12):

I disabled and uninstalled a bunch of Visual Studio extensions, which didn't help.  I then cleared my nuget cache and that solved my problem.

Comment: Likewise, but I had to build the solution afterwards before it would work.

Comment: This is correct. I had the OP's problem and clearing Nuget cache, plus restoring missing Nuget packages cleared it up.

Comment: By "clearing the cache" do you mean just deleting everything in the packages folder?

Comment: No.  In the menu Tools / Options / NuGet Package Manager.  Then click on the "Clear Package Cache" button.  This seemed to work for me at first, but I'm getting the problem again now.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem apparently, in my case it was a reference problem try deleting them one by one until the it starts responding in real time, i suggest starting with 3rd party dlls.