# Visual Studio 2013 freezes on context menu Add

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've just moved a solution from VS2012 to 2013 (the solution has about 21 different projects).

The problem i have is with the context menu for solution explorer for an ASP MVC project, **after i right click on a folder when i hover over the Add submenu VS freezes for about 30 seconds or so**.

The same thing happens when i right click the Service References folder in the project (when i right click, not when i hover over something).
What i've tried:

1. Clearing the NuGet cache see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27530207/visual-studio-freezes-when-i-try-to-add-a-file)
2. Stating in safe mode(this solves the problem but i still don't know what's causing it)
3. Blank MVC project, different project in the same solution(no problems here)
4. Disabling all the extensions that i can(like web essentials)
5. Restarting PC (no effect)
6. Disabling 'Automatically adjust visual experienced based...' from Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General
7. Deleting the `.suo` files

This is what i have installed

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51641

Installed Version: Professional

Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013   06177-004-0446025-02893
Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013

Visual Basic 2013   06177-004-0446025-02893
Microsoft Visual Basic 2013

Visual C# 2013   06177-004-0446025-02893
Microsoft Visual C# 2013

Visual C++ 2013   06177-004-0446025-02893
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013

Visual F# 2013   06177-004-0446025-02893
Microsoft Visual F# 2013

Visual Studio 2013 Code Analysis Spell Checker   06177-004-0446025-02893
Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2013 Code Analysis Spell Checker

Portions of International CorrectSpell™ spelling correction system © 1993 by Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Third Edition Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin Company. Electronic version licensed from Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio   2.5.12582.28
AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio 2.5.12582.28 
 * Ankh.Package 2.5.12582.28
 * Subversion 1.8.11 via SharpSvn 1.8011.3473.77

SharpSvn is linked to: Apr 1.5.1, Apr-util 1.5.4, Cyrus Sasl 2.1.25, eXpat 2.1.0, OpenSSL 1.0.1l 15 Jan 2015, serf 1.3.8, SQLite 3.7.17, Subversion 1.8.11-SharpSvn-1.8.11, ZLib 1.2.8
SharpSvn is optionally linked to: Berkeley DB 4.4.20, SharpPlink 1.8011.3473.77

ASP.NET and Web Tools   12.4.51016.0
Microsoft Web Developer Tools contains the following components:
Support for creating and opening ASP.NET web projects
Browser Link: A communication channel between Visual Studio and browsers
Editor extensions for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript
Page Inspector: Inspection tool for ASP.NET web projects
Scaffolding: A framework for building and running code generators
Server Explorer extensions for Microsoft Azure Websites
Web publishing: Extensions for publishing ASP.NET web projects to hosting providers, on-premises servers, or Microsoft Azure

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.21001.0
For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.21010.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

Crystal Reports for .NET Framework   
Crystal Reports for .NET Framework


NuGet Package Manager   2.8.60318.734
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio   12.1.0.2.0
Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio Copyright (c) 2005, 2014

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   12.0.41012.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure if this will do, that's why I just write it in the comment but you could try it out real quick. Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General and disable 'Automatically adjust visual experienced based...' and uncheck the two checkboxes below.

Comment: @Baha unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: [Here are a ton of other things to try](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617670/why-vs-2013-is-very-slow)

Comment: @br4d Thanks for the link, but this is more of a solution explorer problem than one that affects the entire IDE (except the problems above VS is as "fast" as always)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a few hours a going through the `.csproj` file i've finally managed to figure it out. It was a referenced `.dll` file that was causing this problem.

If you encounter this problem i suggest going to there References folder and deleting them one by one until Visual Studio starts responding in real time, also i think you should start with 3rd party assemblies first.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from toby, my case was due to specific references whose paths were not resolved within a project. I checked the Path property of each of the offending references and verified which ones were truly invalid, and removed only those references and rebuilt the project. Once this was complete the Add context menu returned to normal.