# Visual Studio hangs for several minutes when trying to Right Click and add anything

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I'm collaborating on a project and the team is using TFS 2013 for source control. I have no connection issues and checking in/out is pretty fast.

The problem is that whenever I try to add a new file, which I do by Right-Clicking a folder or a project to add a new Item or create a new folder, Visual Studio becomes unresponsive for several minutes before the context menu pops up, and then for another several minutes when I try to open the `Add` child menu. Afterward, actually adding the item/folder is fast. Obviously this is severely killing my productivity.

[image]

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 5, and I don't encounter this issue when working with local projects or projects using other source control systems so I reckon this somehow relates to TFS? the only extension I have is Productivity PowerTools and NUnit Test Adapter. I have tried the TFS Go Offline extension but that didn't help.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? any thoughts on how to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't this has to be reported directly to Microsoft support?

Comment: happening to me also on VS2015 when renaming files

Comment: tried clearing out your TFS cache?

Comment: Is this a occasional  issue or it happens every time?

Comment: @timB33 tried that, didn't have any effect.

Comment: @Chamberlain every single time unfortunately, I'm currently doing a half-arsed workaround by copy pasting items in instead of trying to go Add -> etc., so I just experience the hang once.

Comment: @SaebAmini, 1). If you work with another Visual Studio 2013 to open the same source controlled project, will the VS2013 hangs as well? 2). Does that project reference any NuGet dlls? Another stackoverflow case discusses the similar issue, and many community members resolved it via go to: Tools-> Options-> NuGet Package Manager-> "Clear Package Cache". See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27530207/visual-studio-freezes-when-i-try-to-add-a-file

Comment: @Vicky-MSFT, thanks for your response. Yes, I've even tried another machine as well as another instance of VS on the same machine, it still hangs. I also came across that post during my research and tried clearing the package cache to no avail.